# x509 - O conjunto de chaves não está definido

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Utilizo a classe `x509certificate` do *C#* para ler um certificado *A3* para assinatura de *XML*, ocorre que foi necessário renovar o certificado e a principio nada mudou, continuou mesmo tipo, mas ao tentar assinar agora está dando o erro:

> "**O conjunto de chaves não está definido**"

O erro ocorre no exato momento que tento ler a *private key* dele utilizando o "`X509Cert.PrivateKey`".

Segue código:

```
////Seleciona o armazenamento de certificado usado pelo usuário atual.
            X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection collection1 = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, _xnome, false);
            if (collection1.Count == 0)
            {
                resultado = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                //Certificado ok
                X509Cert = collection1[0];
                string x;

                //Retorna informações do algoritmo para esse certificado X.509v3 como uma cadeia de caracteres. (Herdado de X509Certificate.)
                x = X509Cert.GetKeyAlgorithm().ToString();

                //Cria um novo documento xml
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                //Formata o documento para ignorar espaços
                doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;

                try
                {
                    //Carregar o arquivo XML pelo nome                    
                    doc.LoadXml(_conteudoXml);                        
                    List<XmlNode> nodes = new List<XmlNode>();
                    foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//*['Signature']"))
                    {
                        nodes.Add(node);
                    }
                    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToString(node.Name) == "Signature")
                        {
                            node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);                             
                        }

                    }

                    //Verifica se a tag a ser assinada existe é única
                    int qtdeRefUri = doc.GetElementsByTagName(_RefUri).Count;

                    if (qtdeRefUri == 0)
                    {
                        //A URI indicada não existe
                        resultado = 2;
                    }
                    //Exsiste mais de uma tag a ser assinada
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < qtdeRefUri; i++)
                            {
                                //Cria o objeto SignedXml.
                                SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);

                                //Define o objeto de AsymmetricAlgorithm que representa a chave particular associada com um certificado.
                                signedXml.SigningKey = X509Cert.PrivateKey;

                                //Cria a referência a ser assinada
                                Reference reference = new Reference();

                                //Pega o uri que deve ser assinada
                                XmlAttributeCollection _Uri = doc.GetElementsByTagName(_RefUri).Item(i).Attributes;

                                foreach (XmlAttribute _atributo in _Uri)
                                {
                                    //Verifica se a URI informada possui o Id
                                    if (_atributo.Name == "Id")
                                    {
                                        reference.Uri = "#" + _atributo.InnerText;
                                    }
                                }

                                //Adiciona o envelopamento para referência
                                XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
                                reference.AddTransform(env);

                                //Adiciona a Canonatização para referência
                                XmlDsigC14NTransform c14 = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
                                reference.AddTransform(c14);

                                //Adiciona referência para o SignedXml objeto.
                                signedXml.AddReference(reference);

                                //Cria novo objeto KeyInfo
                                KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();

                                //Carrega o certificado e insere KeyInfoX509Data                                    
                                keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(X509Cert));

                                //Adiciona Keyinfo para o SignedXml.
                                signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

                                //Adiciona a assinatura no XML com autenticação por ser chave privada
                                signedXml.ComputeSignature();

                                //Referencia xml, coloca assinatura e salva                                    
                                XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

                                //Assina no final da Uri informada.
                                XmlElement xmlElement = doc.GetElementsByTagName(_RefUri)[i] as XmlElement;
                                xmlElement.ParentNode.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

                                XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
                                XMLDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
                                XMLDoc = doc;
                            }
                        }
                        catch (CryptographicException ex)
                        {
                            resultado = 3;
                        }
                    }
```

Dei uma pesquisada, mas não encontrei nada referente a isto. Também procurei verificar se não era permissão de acesso, mas a chave está normal.

Comment: Verifique nas propriedades do certificado se o mesmo está válido, procure pelas novas cadeias `v7` e instale.

Comment: Tente trocar `signedXml.SigningKey = X509Cert.PrivateKey` por `signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();`